# Python: Math Formula and its variables recognition

Tags: python, variables, math, formula

I'd like to write a program that will recognize a math formula and ask the user to enter values and display the result.
  Without EVAL function

1. The program must recognize 4 variables.
2. The program must recognize arithmetical operators (+,-,*,/, [^,()] -> extra)
3. r=a(+,-,*,/)b …, -> get the equation parse the values, ask for values and print the result.

What I have now is:

```
formul=raw_input('Enter your formula: ")
a=input("Value a: ")
b=input("Value b: ")
c=input("Value c: ")
d=input("Value d: ")
```

Comment: Is this a college assignment?

Comment: Both the answers that have been given use `eval()`. Is that OK with you or do you really need to avoid that function? Also, your given code does absolutely nothing to evaluate any operator. Don't you have more? If not, do you really know enough to handle this assignment?

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice one, you can use eval and catch everytime there is a NameError. something like this

```
import re

variables = {}
formula = raw_input('Insert formula: ')
while True:
    try:
        res = eval(formula, variables)
    except NameError as e:
        v = re.match('name .(\w+). is not defined', e.message).group(1)
        variables[v] = input('insert value for %s: ' % v)
        continue
    print ("%s = %s" % (formula, res))
    break
```

the output is something like

```
Insert formula: me + you
insert value for me: 10
insert value for you: 100
me + you = 110
```

Comment: Does this handle the four variables?

Comment: yes it does, it actually does any number of variables and operations

Answer (score 0):

```
formula=formula.replace("a", str(a)).replace("b",str(b)).replace("c", str(c)).replace("d", str(d))

print eval(formula)
```